# Layered navigation is not working for configurable product in Magento

Tags: theme, layered-navigation

I'm stuck at layer navigation enable for frondend site.

1. Click on category->display setting-> Is anchor set to "Yes".
2. Open attribute and set layered navigation -> yes.
3. reindex from system->index management
4. Remove cache

Still I can't see filtration at fronend

[I want filtration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZGQu.png)

Comment: Is the layered navigation block present in your template? Check the `catalog.xml` or `local.xml` in your templates layout directory

Comment: Thamx for reply. I think block is available there. 
 <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
 <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>

Comment: It should be under the `catalog_category_layered` handle, block type `catalog/layer_view`. Also, make sure there are actually results for the filter options. Otherwise they won't show

Comment: yes block is available there.All products are configurable. And each config products is working properly [see here](http://w81227.php5.sysedata.no/index.php/cars-rims.html)

Comment: this theme you created from scratch or you buy this theme?

Comment: bought it. I'm newbie for magento.

Comment: To debug theme issues please test with the reference theme from Magento (just switch to "default" package) - update with your finding.